# Output redirection to file

Tags: linux, shell, io-redirection

When I'm redirecting a command output to a file with `>` the file is created in "DOS format", after which I have to invoke the `dos2unix` command on the file if I want the file to be unix formated.

Is there any way to do this directly from the redirecting command and avoid after processing the file?

P.S. I'm using ubuntu, so I don't understand why is the file created in DOS format in the first place...

Comment: which command exactly? what exactly you mean by "DOS format"?

Comment: In DOS files new lines are displayed differently then in linux files.
The command that output I want to redirect is a `tail` command, for getting the last line from a file: `tail -1 filename.txt > lastline.txt`

Comment: DOS = CRLF, Unix = LF, Mac = CR

Comment: @user2250673 It mostly likely is not tail that is creating the DOS line endings. What is creating the file that you are tailing? Whatever is creating that file, is probably the source of the DOS line endings.

Comment: You are right, an android `adb` command is creating the file like this:
`adb shell monkey [some params] > file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You can run multiple commands in one line by separating your commands with a colon `;`

Example:

`your_cmd > your_outfile ; dos2unix your_outfile`

Comment: I know that, but I want to resolve that in one command if it's possible. I want to avoid creating the file in DOS format and reformat it after.

Answer (score 1):

If your `dos2unix` can be used as a filter (as unix utility programs usually can), you can pipe the output to it like this:

```
command | dos2unix > file
```

In your case:

```
tail -1 filename.txt | dos2unix > lastline.txt
```

Comment: I don't want to use `dos2unix`.

Comment: @user2250673  Why not, when it will give you the result you want in one step, without creating an intermediate file?